# Rudin Real and Complex Ch.2 question 16

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

This excerise 2.16 in Rudin is as follows:
Let X be the plane with the following topology: a set is open iff it's intersection with every vertical line is an open subset of that line w/ respect to the standard topology on R^1. If f is a continuous function with compact support, let x_1...x_n be the points s.t the vertical line through said x has at least one y in the support of f. There are only finitely many such x.

I don't understand why there are only finitely many such x. Couldn't any closed box in the plane contain the support of such an f and so there would be an interval (x_1,x_2) where every vertical line intersecting the interval has some y in f's support? Someone please correct my thinking but leave as much of the exercise as possible for me to do. Thank you :)

Comment: It seems that your topology is a product topology of the Euclidean one on $\Bbb R$ and the discrete one on $\Bbb R$. Compact subsets of discrete spaces are exactly finite sets.

Comment: How'd you get to that conclusion?( that the topology is the product you mentioned, not the compact part)?

Comment: Haven't dealt with topology for some time, so intuition. I think you can consider a product topology (say, define it to be generated by projection maps) and try to see what are exactly open sets in this topology. Note: I'm not sure that this is indeed the product topology in your problem - just thought it's worth checking this.

Comment: That's some intuition :p. but thanks I'll try it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your closed box could certainly contain the support of such an $f$, but it cannot be equal to the support. Be careful that a closed box is *not* compact in the topology you are looking at.

Here is a "hint": if you denote by $A$ the set of all $x$ with the above property, then the sets $\{ x\}\times \mathbb R$ are open (in the topology you are looking at) and cover the support of $f$.

Last remark: Ilya is perfectly right. A set is open in your topology if and only if it is a union of sets of the form $\{ x\}\times V$, where $V$ is open in $\mathbb R$. This means exactly that your topology is the product of the discrete and the usual topology of $\mathbb R$.